# node compile.js doesn't generate combined css file

Tags: css, node.js, dojo, themes, customization

I finally figured out how to prepare and run the "node compile.js" file from the claro theme folder, so that it compiles each *.less file into its associated *.css file, but the old claro.css file is left as is.

Is that intended?  If so, then what is the process for updating the claro.css file to reflect all the changes to the individual *.css files?   Up to now I've always had the claro.css file imported into my jsp file like so:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
```

Am I missing something?  Using the node tool (and the provided "compile.js" file in the claro theme directory) to generate a custom theme based on the claro theme is great, but what about the step to update the large claro.css file?   Please tell me I'm missing something to complete this customization process.

Thank you in advance,

Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way Dijit themes are traditionally structured, yes, this is intended.  `claro.css` doesn't contain any styles of its own, it simply contains `@import`s to each individual file which is being compiled by `compile.js`.

Dojo's build system is already capable of flattening CSS imports, so that is the point at which `claro.css` ordinarily becomes a flattened file with all of the rules from the individual widgets' CSS files.

Comment: Thanks Ken for the clarification.  I never saw the claro.css file with the @imports - so it appears that somehow I had originally installed dojo1.9.1 with the claro.css file already compiled and flattened. Not sure how that happened.  What would be my best next step(s) to achieve an updated claro.css file?   I'll start researching how to start from a version with the imports and build it if necessary.  Again - any helpful pointer will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: That would explain your previous question (specifically why you didn't have `util` for `compile.js` to Just Work) as well.  It sounds like you downloaded a release archive instead of a source archive.  Each Dojo release (e.g. http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.10.4/) has both - the source archive is the one with `-src` in the name.

Comment: Yes - I went back to the Dojo download page and saw exactly that.  I had originally downloaded the release archive instead of the source archive.  And I see that only the source archive contains the util folder.  Makes a lot more sense now.  I just now downloaded the source archive and copied the claro.css from it to get the version with the import statements.  Now I need to figure out how to build the flattened version to get the claro.css with the files imported.  Thanks again.